# Redis - Make failover master return to slave state and master take up it's old master role

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, failover

I have a Redis v4.0.7 cluster consisting of 4 servers. These 4 servers are all running Ubuntu v17.10 64 bit Virtual Machines (in VirtualBox) that I have on my Windows PC. I have shifted all the slaves 1 server and will be using M1 for master 1 as well as S1 for slave 1 in the following explanation of my "issue".

- 192.168.56.101 (with a master on port 7000 (M1) and slave on port 7001 (S4))
- 192.168.56.102 (with a master on port 7000 (M2) and slave on port 7001 (S1))
- 192.168.56.103 (with a master on port 7000 (M3) and slave on port 7001 (S2))
- 192.168.56.104 (with a master on port 7000 (M4) and slave on port 7001 (S3))

I am fiddling a little bit with the setup to check if the failover "works".

Therefore I have tried shutting down M2, which means that S2 takes over and becomes the master. This works as intended. However if I start up the (old) M2 again it is now a slave and remains as such until I shut S2 down at which point it will take over the master role again.

I was wondering if there is a certain command that I can issue to the slave that has taken over the master role which makes it take over it's (old) slave role and hand over the master role to the (old) master, in this case M2.

I have tried googling the "issue", but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running:

```
redis-cli -h M2_IP_ADDRESS M2_PORT CLUSTER FAILOVER
```

Above command will make manual failover. M2 will became master and S2 slave.